# Basis of system of equation and how to convert these equation to vector form?

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis and dimension of the solution space  of the following system of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
x &+& y &+& z &= 1\\
2x &+& y &+& 2z &= 1\\
x &+& 2y &+& 3z &= 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're talking about systems of linear equations, basis and dimension of vector subspaces I'm gonna assume you know what Gaussian Elimination is, otherwise I highly suggest you check out: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html

To solve your problem we use the Gaussian elimination on the matrix: $$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]\rightarrow\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 4 & -4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Which gives us the system of equations:
$$\begin{array}{ r @{{}={}} r  >{{}}c<{{}} r  >{{}}c<{{}}  r }
x & + & y&  + &z&=&  1 \\
-y &=&  -1               \\
4z &=&    -4&\\ 
\end{array}$$
That has the solution $$V=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$
If we consider the linear map $L_A(x)=Ax$ where $$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix} $$
$L_A$ has rank $3$ since $A$ has rank $3$ thus $Ker(A)=\{0\}$ thus the solution to the system it's unique and the solution space $W$ has dimension $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 &  1 \\ 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$ $=$ $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

$Det(A)=-2$ Which means there exists a $A^{-1}$ and system has a uniqe solution

According to Cramer`s Rule  where $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are column vectors of A and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

$x=\frac{Det(B,A_2,A_3)}{Det(A_1,A_2,A_3)}=2$